# Boost program_options store multiple config file parse results into one parsed_options

Tags: c++, boost

I'm trying to parse unregistered options in any number of files provided at command line. Let's say I have files:

```
configs0.ini
configs1.ini
configs2.ini
```

And I wanted to support any number of these.

My code (simplified):

```
namespace po = boost::program_options;
po::options_description cmd_opts{"Options"};
po::options_description config_file_opts;
po::variables_map vm;

cmd_opts.add_options()                                                                                                                                                                                                     
   ("help,h", "Help message")                                       
   ("config_files", po::value<std::vector<std::string>>()->multitoken(), "Configuration files to get settings from")

po::parser.options(reg_config_file_opts).allow_unregistered();

po::store(parse_command_line(argc, argv, cmd_opts), vm);

config_files = vm["config_files"].as<std::vector<std::string>>();
po::parsed_options parsed_opts;

for(auto file : config_files) {
   std::ifstream ifs(file, std::ifstream::in);                                                                                                                                                                             
   if(ifs.fail()) {
      std::cerr << "Error opening config file: " << file << std::endl;
      return false;
   }
   ifs.close();

   <NEED HELP HERE>
   parsed_opt.add(parse_config_file(ifs, reg_config_file_opts));
}

po::store(parsed_opts, vm);
```

Does parsed_options have some sort of .add ability?

Answer (score 3):

The library [distinguishes three layers](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/doc/html/program_options/overview.html#id-1.3.31.5.11):

- the description component
- the parsers component
- the storage component

The design assumes that you will be using one or more sets of descriptions with one or more parsers, and combine the results into one storage.

In practice this means you will store into the same variable map, and notify to update any value-semantics with side-effects.

**<strike>Live</strike> Demo**

- File `main.cpp`

  ```
  #include <boost/program_options.hpp>
  #include <boost/program_options/cmdline.hpp>
  #include <boost/program_options/config.hpp>
  #include <fmt/format.h>
  #include <fmt/ranges.h>
  #include <fstream>

  namespace po = boost::program_options;

  int main() {
      for (auto args : {
              std::vector{"test.exe"},
              std::vector{"test.exe", "--config_files", "a.cfg", "b.cfg", "c.cfg"},
          })
      {
          int const argc    = args.size();
          char const** argv = args.data();

          po::options_description cmd_opts{"Options"};

          using values = std::vector<std::string>;
          cmd_opts.add_options()                                                                                                                                                                                                     
              ("help,h", "Help message")                                       
              ("config_files", po::value<values>()->multitoken(), "Configuration files to get settings from")
              ;

          po::variables_map vm;
          po::variables_map cfg_vm; // can also reuse vm
          po::store(parse_command_line(argc, argv, cmd_opts), vm);

          auto& config_files = vm["config_files"];
          if (!config_files.empty()) {

              po::options_description config_file_opts;
              config_file_opts.add_options()                                                                                                                                                                                                     
                  ("foo", po::value<values>()->composing())
                  ("bar_a", po::value<values>()->composing())
                  ("bar_b", po::value<values>()->composing())
                  ("bar_c", po::value<values>()->composing())
                  ;

              for(auto file : config_files.as<values>()) try {
                  std::ifstream ifs(file);
                  po::store(parse_config_file(ifs, config_file_opts), cfg_vm);
              } catch(std::exception const& e) {
                  fmt::print(stderr, "{}: {}\n", file, e.what());
              }

              fmt::print("Cmdline opts\n");
              for (auto& [k, v] : vm) {
                  fmt::print("{}={}\n", k, v.as<values>());
              }
              fmt::print("Combined configs\n");
              for (auto& [k, v] : cfg_vm) {
                  fmt::print("{}={}\n", k, v.as<values>());
              }
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- File `a.cfg`

  ```
  foo=foo_val_a
  bar_a=bar_val_a
  ```
- File `b.cfg`

  ```
  foo=foo_val_b
  bar_b=bar_val_b
  ```
- File `c.cfg`

  ```
  foo=foo_val_c
  bar_c=bar_val_c
  ```

Prints:

```
Cmdline opts
config_files={"a.cfg", "b.cfg", "c.cfg"}
Combined configs
bar_a={"bar_val_a"}
bar_b={"bar_val_b"}
bar_c={"bar_val_c"}
foo={"foo_val_a", "foo_val_b", "foo_val_c"}
```